# keep socket alive when page/browser is idle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I am using socket.io for real time communication. I am facing problem when user's browser is idle. I mean, suppose there is two entity 'User A' and 'User B'. User A wants to talk with User B. If User B has opened the application but is not active on that page then User A cannot contact User B because the socket of User B is disconnected after some minutes when the system is idle. Also I don't see continuous polling on ws tab inside network

Here is the code to configure socket. I am using context API

```
const SocketProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [socketClient, setSocketClient] = React.useState();
  const [socketUpdated, setSocketUpdated] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io(SOCKET_URL, {
      path: "/socket.io"
    });
    setSocketClient(socket);
    // return () => {
    //   io.disconnect();
    // };
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (socketClient !== undefined) {
      if (user) { // from localstorage
        console.log("user", user);
        socketClient.on("connect", () => {
          socketClient.emit("userData", {
            _id: user._id,
            socketId: socketClient.id
          });
        });

        // socketClient.on("connected", msg => {
        //   console.log("connected msg", msg);
        //   setSocketUpdated(true);
        // });
        // setSocketUpdated(true);
      }
    }
  }, [socketClient]);

  return (
    <>
      <SocketContext.Provider value={{ socket: socketClient, socketUpdated }}>
        {children}
      </SocketContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export { SocketContext, SocketProvider };
```

I want socket on multiple pages so for single socket reference I have used socket in context. Wherever I need socket, I import this context and use it accordingly.

How can I handle disconnection issue so the socket is still alive when user's system/browser is idle?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422741/activate-idle-inactive-connections maybe this will help

Comment: there he talks about application level which i am not clear on.